# OGR2OGR -overwrite mssql table is appending instead

Tags: sql-server, ogr2ogr

I am running

```
Command '['C:\\OSGeo4W\\bin\\ogr2ogr.exe', '-progress', '-skipfailures', '-overwrite', '-lco', 'UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt',
 '-t_srs', 'EPSG:28354', '-f', 'MSSQLSpatial', 'MSSQL:Server=xxx;Database=xxxGIS_Test;Trusted_Connect
ion=True', 'D:\\GIS_SourceData\\xxx\\HY_WATERBODY_STATE.tab', '-nln', 'DSE_HY_WATERBODY_STATE']'
```

But this is appending records to the table in MSSQL instead of overwriting the whole table?

Is there some switch to just tell it to update records/insert new ones or what should I do to get -overwrite to not append?

[image]

The _backup view is the original that was just backed up before running the command.

UPDATED EXAMPLE
[image]

WITH DEBUG
[image]
Is there a way in OGR to delete the table or delete the records in the table before overwrite?

Comment: do you get the expected result if you include the `-update` flag?

Comment: @SaultDon I tried this but get the same result...i.e change -overwrite to -update

Comment: Don't swap em, need both, and add both of these too `-lco OVERWRITE=YES` and `-append`

Comment: @SaultDon upfrotunately the same result. Will update the question with screen grab

Comment: @SaultDon I have tried with/without -append, -update and -overwrite and also moved these just before but keep getting the same result. It is happening to all the tables this process runs on. I am using OGR that comes with the current QGIS LTR (3.4)

Comment: I don't know much about mssql tables, but for postgresql ones you can just use `-append` with `--config OGR_TRUNCATE YES`

Comment: @SaultDon hopefully this behaviour should be the same but can you see anything wrong with the structure of this command? [ogr2ogr -progress -skipfailures -overwrite -update -lco OVERWRITE=YES -lco UPLOAD_GEOM_FORMAT=wkt --config OGR_TRUNCATE YES -f "MSSQLSpatial" "MSSQL:Server=xxxltz;Database=xxx_GIS_Test;Trusted_Connection=True" -t_srs EPSG:28354 "D:\GIS_SourceData\Data\DSE\xxxap\VMREFTAB\TR_ROAD_SEAL.TAB" -nln "DSE_TR_ROAD_SEAL"] ?

Comment: if you're gonna try thE TRUNCATE config option. can replace both -overwrite and -update with just -append. also the -lco options wont have any effect because the layer already exists

Comment: Because the driver has its own overwrite option https://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html then I guess that it is made for purpose and the `-overwrite` option of ogr2ogr is not needed at all. Have you tried with just `-lco OVERWRITE=YES`?

Comment: @user30184 I tried this but get the same result...is there a safe way (in ogr2ogr or some other command line) to delete all records or the table before putting the data into it? It can't be in SQL server manager as I am running this in task scheduler via a batch file.

Comment: I suppose that there is something special in your environment. Make one more test by adding `--debug on` into your command and see if it gives some more information. It would also help if you could see the logs from the database server. Otherwise I believe that the main developer of the MSSQL driver reads the mails from gdal-dev mailing list.

Comment: @user30184 I get a couple of errors with this but it uploads the data anyway -although it doesn't overwrite. See updated Q.

Comment: I just noticed that if I rename the old table (or delete it), then I can run the process multiple times and it doesn't duplicate the data. Has anyone noticed this behaviour when moving from a non-OGR table update process to a OGR2OGR process? Initially it was done using Mapinfo EasyLoader.

Comment: Have you tried the layer creation option `GEOMETRY_NAME: Set the name of geometry column in the new table. If omitted it defaults to ogr_geometry` for making ogr2ogr to insert geometries into SP_GEOMETRY?

Comment: @user30184 same issue. It seems to be something to do with how the table was originally created. This was done using EASYLOADER from Mapinfo and uploading tab files but if the table is renamed before running OGR, on subsequent runs it doesn't append. BTW I found -al would dump the contents ... https://www.gdal.org/drv_mssqlspatial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there seems to be an issue when OGR wasn't used to initially create the table in MSSQL. It maybe just for tables created by Pitney Bowes "Easyloader" and may not happen if the table was created by other systems.

So simply deleting/renaming the table before running the OGR2OGR command the first time, ensures that the data is just updated/replaced and not appended in subsequent calls.

Thanks to all the help here I found a lot of interesting switches that aren't clearly documented.